# Read and save a csv file with the name of a variable

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have the following variable:

```
      Id_Sensor = 406
```

This variable value is used to read the input file and to save the output dataframe. According to the codes below:

```
      # Read archive csv
      df_Sensor = pd.read_csv('C:/User/Desktop/Data/SENSOR/PROJ01_406.csv')

      # Save the archive
      df_Sensor.to_csv('PROJ01_IDENTIF406_test.csv')
```

I would like the name ID sensor to be automatic when reading the file and when saving. Why do I need to write the number 406 manually. Is there a way to insert the value of a variable inside the functions pd.read_csv and to_csv?

Comment: I don't know if it's what you need but just add variables with the default name/path and append the id_sensor value as str. It would be like : "PROJ01_IDENTF" + str(id_Sensor) + "_test.csv". Same for reading

Answer (score 6):

Lots of ways to do it.  Take your pick!

Using `%` formatting:

```
df_Sensor = pd.read_csv('C:/User/Desktop/Data/SENSOR/PROJ01_%s.csv' % Id_Sensor)
```

Using `.format()`:

```
df_Sensor = pd.read_csv('C:/User/Desktop/Data/SENSOR/PROJ01_{0}.csv'.format(Id_Sensor))
```

Using f-strings:

```
df_Sensor = pd.read_csv(f'C:/User/Desktop/Data/SENSOR/PROJ01_{Id_Sensor}.csv')
```